# Understanding classes?

Tags: c#, class

Why this part code don't running and show message "cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type name instead"? Please about explain me.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
       public Form1()
        {
        }

       public class Report //my public class
        {
            public static double[] KwotaZ = new double[10];
            public static double[] KwotaNa = new double[10];
            public static string[] WalutaNa = new string[10];
            public static string[] WalutaZ = new string[10];
            public static int IlOperacji = 0;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report raport2 = new Report(); //create new object class Report
            raport2.KwotaZ[raport2.IlOperacji] = 213.3; //this wrong part code why???
            Konwerter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Report is a static class while button1_Click is NON-static method

Comment: Because `KwotaZ` is static.  If those arrays should exist in each new object, they should not be static.

Comment: You have referenced static field (for instance) `IlOperacji` by instance name.

Comment: you define class into class????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using static variables with an instance.  there is only ever 1 static variable.

So you should either use it statically like so

```
Report.KwotaZ[Report.IlOperacji] = 213.3;
```

or define them as instance variables like so(without the `static` keyword)

```
public double[] KwotaZ = new double[10];
public int IlOperacji = 0;
```

Comment: Ok, I define them as instance variables without the static keyword, but appear new problem.
Second partial class (Form4) has other problem, when i want to assign form1.report2.KwotaZ[0].ToString();

Comment: Second class:

public partial class Form4 : Form
        {
            private Form1 form1;
            public Form4(Form1 form1)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.form1 = form1;
            }
    
            private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
               for(int i=0; i< form1.report2.ilOperacji;i++)
                richTextBox1.Text = form1.report2.KwotaZ[0].ToString();
    
            }
         }

Comment: @Gugunion If you have another question than you should make another question.

Answer (score 2):

`KwotaZ` and `IlOperacji` are `static` fields, so the syntax to access them is not `instance.fieldName` -- it is `TypeName.fieldName`, as in

```
Report.KwotaZ[Report.IlOperacji] = 213.3;
```

This will allow the program to compile, but it's probably not what you want. It's much more likely that you should make the `static` fields into instance properties:

```
public class Report //my public class
{
    // Only showing two properties here; do the rest in the same manner
    public double[] KwotaZ { get; set; }
    public double[] KwotaNa = { get; set; }

    public Report()
    {
        this.KwotaZ = new double[10];
        this.KwotaNa = new double[10];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the "static" keyword in your "Report" class.  "static" means that there is only 1 copy of the variable.  For example, even if you create 5 instances of the "Report" class, they will all have the same value for "KwotaZ".

What you probably want is to remove the "static" keyword.  That way, each instance of "Report" will have its own version of the variables.